# MySQL 5 java.sql.SQLException: Can't find file: 'time_zone' (errno: 2)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, spring-jdbc

Am trying to use this Spring based JDBC query on a Amazon ec2-instance which is running MySQL 5.5.57. This query works on other Linux systems but on this particular one, I think my MySQL database might have been corrupted somehow.

Using Java 1.7 and Spring 4, here's my JDBC query:

```
SqlRowSet rst = null;

rst = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet("select * from order_schedule where date(convert_tz(order_date_time,'UTC','US/Pacific'))=date(convert_tz(now(), @@system_time_zone, 'US/Pacific'))");
```

This is what I am getting inside my logs under Tomcat 7:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can't find file: 'time_zone' (errno: 2)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:25)
```

The basics of my query is that to convert the time inside the order_schedule table's order_date_time to UTC time. This works on other servers but somehow MySQL 5 became corrupted.

Does anyone know what this error is caused? How can I revert MySQL 5 back to its original settings?

Comment: When you installed this MySQL instance, did you do the steps described in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html under "*Populating the Time Zone Tables*"?

Comment: Instead of `US/Pacific`, try `America/Los_Angeles`

Comment: @BillKarwin - Think someone else followed these instructions from the 8.0 manual. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html  And this is why it broke... This person is on PTO so does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Find another person who is not on PTO and is able to follow the steps in the documentation for populating the time zone tables.

Comment: @BilKarwin - That person is me :) my question is that did this person do the right thing by trying to populate the timezone tables? Isn't MySQL 5 come loaded with timezone tables?

Comment: Per the doc page: "The MySQL installation procedure creates the time zone tables, but does not load them. You must do so manually using the following instructions."

Comment: I assume that MySQL does not load data into these tables because the timezones recognized by your system depends on the operating system, so MySQL cannot predict what to load. You have to gather that timezone data on the OS you install on. You can also re-run the timezone load from time to time, if the list of timezones in the OS changes. This is also mentioned in that doc page.

Comment: The errno 2 ("no such file or directory") is a little puzzling. The tables should at least exist, even if they are empty. Anyway, it's safe to recreate them if you need to.

Comment: @BillKarwin - I rebooted the server and the exception is gone! :) Need to run some more queries before I can say whether this works or not.

Comment: @BillKarwin - Yes, the query you provided shows me the time_zone table.

Comment: The fact that you got errno 2 and now you don't is actually *more* alarming. Files aren't supposed to come and go randomly. Maybe this is the fault of SELinux, which is known to return "file not found" if a service tries to access a file that is not in the proscribed location. What does the command `getenforce` tell you? (should be "Enabled" if SELinux is active or "Disabled" if SELinux is not enabled)

Comment: @BillKarwin The command returns Disabled.

Comment: That may explain why it works now. That is, SELinux is not currently blocking access to the file that stores the time_zone table. But it may have been before you rebooted, if someone had done `setenforce 1` to enable it in an ad hoc way, without enabling it persistently over reboots.

Comment: @BillKarwin - Thanks that's good to know.